# Declaring objects with try statement

Tags: java, exception

```
try {
  Man Fred = new Man();
} catch (exception e) {
  Print e 
}

Print Fred.getName ();
```

Fred is now out of scope. How should I be doing this?

Comment: I don't really see how this is valid Java syntax... ;)

Comment: @brimborium Looks like pseudo code :P

Comment: @LewsTherin Not really, more like a mix of pseudo code and Java...

Comment: Yep, does that make it an hybrid?

Comment: @LewsTherin No, that makes it ugly code with syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem aware of Java syntax so in pseudo

```
 Man Fred = null;
    try {
      Fred = new Man();
    } catch (exception e) {
      print e 
    } finally {
       //You could do some clean up.
    }

    if(Fred != null) {
      print Fred.getName();
    }
```

If not..

```
   Man fred = null;
   try {
      fred = new Man();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
    } finally {
       //You could do some clean up.
    }

    if(fred != null) {
      System.out.println(fred.getName());
    }
```

The Fred variable has to be declared outside the try block. So it is visible in method or outer scope.

Comment: @LewsTherin Nope, Duncan only edited the question, but is not OP... ;)

Comment: @brimborium Yeah my bad. I just woke up :)

Comment: Oh and you shouldn't delete comments unless neccessary. It will make discussions in the comments irritating to others (as will happen here :D). Good morning btw!

Comment: @brimborium I actually deleted it before I saw your comment. But point taken ;) And thanks!

Answer (score 4):

And now in proper Java:

```
Man fred = null;
try {
  fred = new Man();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(); 
}

if (fred != null) {
  System.out.println(fred.getName());
}
```

You'll have to declare the variable inside the code block where you want to access it. In this special case: outside the "try" block.

Comment: Finally. :D Just waited for that one. :P

Answer (score 1):

`Fred` is only available *inside* the `try`-block, since that's where you declared him. Instead, declare him outside the block, like so:

```
Man fred;
try {
    fred = new Man();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (fred != null) {
    System.out.println(fred);
}
```

Note the extra `if (fred != null)`; since creating fred might've thrown an `Exception`, in which case `fred` will be `null`, and printing him might not work.

Comment: So why move the declaration outside the try-block, when you could move the use(s) inside and avoid the test and the initialization to null?

Comment: That'd be a solution too. In a situation where you could live without `fred` and do some other things, you'll use the above solution. On the other hand, if you're sure you don't want to continue without `fred`, you'll want @EJP's solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is as follows:

```
try
{   
    Man fred = new Man(); 
    print(fred.getName()); 
} 
catch (Exception exc) 
{   
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

In other words your 'try' block should be large enough to encompass all the subsequent uses of `fred`. Resist the temptation to make them tiny and sequential. Instead make them large and nested.

Answer (score -1):

See following changes:

```
Man Fred = null; 
Try
{   
    Fred = new Man(); 
} 
catch (exception e) 
{   
    Print e  
}  

If(Fred != null)
{
    Print Fred.getName (); 
}
```

Comment: If? With a capital I? Print? Without parenthesis? If the code is tagged with Java the answer should at least be Java code...

Comment: @Matteo: it was just a pseudocode with Java programming flow not the syntax.